# FSO - DeleteFile issue

Tags: vbscript, fso

I'm running a routine delete all files within a folder, then delete the folder. It works, but always seems to leave one file behind. Assume some kind of file lock, but ideas on how to clear the lock would be appreciated.

If I manually delete the 'rogue' file, and rerun the routine the folder is deleted - so all of my folder permissions are correct.

thanks

```
fso.DeleteFile objFolder & "\*.pdf", true   
fso.DeleteFolder objFolder, true
```

Comment: When you say "delete all files" you're actually only deleting `*.pdf` files. What extension is the file that is left behind?

Comment: All of the files are PDF files.

Answer (score 0):

I've located the issue - it was down to a PDF object further up my page. Once I'd set this to 'Nothing' the fso delete command worked a treat.
thanks

Comment: Glad you fixed it!